# Python: replace value from dataframe if same value is present in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and a list. The dataframe consists of the column 'CODE' and 'distance'. The list consists of a row of values. I want the value in 'CODE' changed to zero if values from the list are also present in the distance column of the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'CODE': np.arange(0, 220), 
                   'distance': np.arange(0, 1100, 5)})

a = [1080, 1090] #list
```

I can do the above operation comparing the dataframe with a single value using the code below.

```
df.loc[df.distance == 1080, 'CODE'] = 0
```

This results in the following outcome:

```
     CODE  distance
3       3        15
4       4        20
..    ...       ...
215   215      1075
216     0      1080
217   217      1085
218   218      1090
```

However, when I try to replace the value 1080 with the list a (see below) it doesn't work. How can I solve this?

```
df.loc[df.distance == a, 'CODE'] = 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df.loc[df.distance.isin(a), 'CODE'] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a function to `df` that checks if `distance` is in `a` and if it is, change the corresponding `CODE` to 0:

```
df['CODE'] = df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x['distance'] in a else x['CODE'], axis=1)
```